# Does OpenGL use fixed point calculations under the hood?

Tags: opengl, pixel, floating-accuracy, fixed-point

As far as I know, OpenGL sticks to a filling convention when rasterizes triangles to avoid pixel gaps and overdraw. But will those conventions make sense if all calculations are done with floats and not with the fixed point floats? So, I think the API does use fixed point types.

Comment: depends on your graphics card, surely.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. When I was writing a software rasterizer, I had gaps in some specific camera position and rotation as well. I've used lots of algorithms and still had pixel stitches. Don't know how OpenGL avoids those problems.

Comment: Exactly the same edges always line up. Gaps can occur if you rely on two edges lining up but the edges aren't exactly the same.

Comment: OpenGL is not a library, it's a specification: [Khronos OpenGL® Registry](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php). The API is implemented by the graphics driver. The graphics driver is implemented by the vendor for a specific GPU. The calculations are hardware accelerated.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that all the vertices were shared in that software rasterizer.

Comment: It's common to get small gaps when you have edges that are meant to be co-linear, but not the same. E.g. if you have three points on a line A---B---C and on top side you have a triangle with edge AC and on the bottom have some different triangles with AB and BC separately, they might not match up exactly. Solution: split up the top triangle into two triangles, one with AB and one with BC

Comment: I think I got your idea, but I have a few questions if you don't mind. Does this exact case involve 3 triangles that are overlapping? Should I split edge before or at the rasterization stage? Hope, I've understood you correctly, thanks!